# Magento 2 method call evrrytime on reload

Tags: magento2, methods

hi I am newb to magento and I am looking for certain process through which magento will call some method  every time whenever its frontend or backend reloads

Comment: You should describe what you want to do because there are a lot of thinks that are always called and they might not fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

`Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::createApplication` is always called and everything that gets called inside it.